# How to enable self-timer in 1dx?

Tags: camera-settings, canon-1d-x, self-timer

I'm having an issue with enabling self-timer in my 1dx. When trying to select any self-timer options, they appear disabled.

Any ideas, why this could be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Custom Function Three (C.Fn3: Drive) in the custom functions menu tab and insure that under "Restrict Drive Modes" that there is a check mark next to the self timer setting you wish to use. If there is no check mark then that drive mode is disabled and not selectable using the *AF-Drive* button.  It is on page 326 of the [1D X Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007358/02/eos1dx-im2-c-en.pdf).